# Get id value to PHP from a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags, modal-dialog

How can i get a variable in PHP with the value of a ID on a div.

Example: `<div class="style" id="13" name="var">text...</div>`

how can i on a PHP or JS, etc..., get the id value for a variable on PHP, to i show.

Example: `$id_div = id` from div with the name var.

```
<?php echo $id_div; ?> // 13.
```

Please help me, i just want to know the value of id propriety and replace on a php variable.

```
<div name="var" id="<?php echo $get["id"]; ?>">
Here i want to show the id propriety on a php variable
</div>
```

Comment: Where is it from the html with the `<div id="">` to catch? It is your own HTML code or is it in external page, or what?

Comment: your question is unclear? Please ask properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div name="var" id="<?php echo $get["id"]; ?>">
    <?php echo $get["id"]; ?>
</div>
```

or with javascript:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[name="var"]');
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div){
    div.textContent = div.id;
});
```

Comment: You mean $_GET['id'] ?

Answer (score 0):

First the `$get["id"];` should be `$_GET["id"];`, and you could store it in some variable and use it where you want :

```
<?php $id = $_GET["id"]; ?>

<div name="var" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php echo $id; ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you want to send this `ids` over server again ? If yes then either `AJAX` of `Form` will be needed...And if you going to deal with `forms` then `input` elements will be needed...